# Supercomputer from old computers

Tags: ubuntu-core

I have many computers sitting around.

- A netbook
- A laptop
- A desktop
- And another Desktop

I was wondering if there is any software that is capable of taking the processing power of the computers and using it to make a powerful server that could host windows or Linux vm?

What kind of connections would you use?

What software could I use?

What applications does this have.

Has anyone done anything like this?

Does this seem do-able.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an old joke on http://slashdot.org about taking a bunch of old computers and making a Beowulf cluster.

Interestingly enough, here's a ZDNet article about someone doing just that using a bunch of Raspberry Pi computers: http://www.zdnet.com/article/build-your-own-supercomputer-out-of-raspberry-pi-boards/

I don't know if you can merge your computers together to make a much larger computer to run a single instance of Linux or Windows. The main issue that you'd run into is the communication between processors. Most computer CPUs need a low-latency/high-bandwidth bus and Gigabit Ethernet just isn't fast enough for this, really.

Though you can create a Virtual Machine cluster out of the faster computers using the (free) ProxMox Virtual Environment: https://www.proxmox.com/

This is totally doable.

Answer (score 1):

You could host a mini cloud using software like MAAS (http://maas.ubuntu.com/).

Using maas you can manage a cluster of computers; you can deploy workloads to them using tools such as juju (juju.ubuntu.com). Maas takes care of booting and installing the computers when juju requests hardware for deployment. Have a read at maas and juju documentation to understand what they do and decide if you like that possibility.

Comment: How could that be accomplished? Please elaborate :-)

Comment: Using maas you can manage a cluster of computers; you can deploy workloads to them using tools such as juju (https://juju.ubuntu.com/). Maas takes care of booting and installing the computers when juju requests hardware for deployment. Have a read at maas and juju documentation to understand what they do and decide if you like that possibility.

Comment: @roadmr: upvote you've got already, now copy-paste the comment into the answer!  :P  ;-)